# What items are considered as bad html

Tags: html

I do use an editor to design email marketing templates. I found out that this editor I am using, when I view the html side code of my design, instead of the `</br>` tag, it places `<br />` with an extra space.

I want to make my emails be as efficient as possible and be anti-spam filter friendly.

Could this be considered bad html code and could land up in spam or be blocked by email recipients?

Also, what could be the best practices in designing email templates and what to avoid?

Sample code:

```
<li><span style="font-family: helvetica; font-size: small;"><font color="#555555"><strong>Customized Marketing Materials...</strong></font> <em>Do you display your products? Are you looking to create more conversation with your clientele or patients about the benefits of supplementation? Check out our NEW SHELF TALKERS! Contact me to find out how to get your FREE Shelf Talker&nbsp;&lt;#my_200&gt; <br /><br /></em></span></li>
</ul>
```

Hoping for your insights.

Comment: Fixing your `br` tags isn't really bad practice.

Comment: Seems the editor knows best ...

Comment: Thanks guys! I am not that expert yet in the html field. So <br /> is a more "preferred correct format" versus </br> or </br >, and the extra space between br and / doesn't matter?

Comment: That is correct, `</br` would actually be invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<br />` is the most common from what I've seen, Visual Studio and so on even auto-corrects to that. Personally, I use `<br>`

Comment: Copy guys, thank you for the insight and clarification, appreciate it!